# JAVA - Understanding looping through a list

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

Write a method removeShorterStringsList that takes an List as a parameter and remove from each successive pair of values the shorter string in the pair.

For example, suppose that an ArrayList called list contains the following values: {"four", "score", "and", "seven", "years", "ago"} removeShorterStringsList would print out {"score", "seven", "years"}.

And with {"hello", "good", "morning"};, would print out {"hello", "morning"} purposefully ignoring the last element whenever size() is odd.

The method I have works for lists that have an even size(). But when I run my method through a list with an odd size() I get an index out of bounds error. Not sure why this is happening though because I have a conditional that increments i. I'm having problems with a list of size 3. If were ignoring the last element and we run through this loop, shouldn't it stop after looping once since i starts at 0, increments at the bottom (1) and once again at the top (2) then 2<2 would stop the loop? Heres my method:

```
public static void removeShorterStringsList(List<String> a) {
        int size = a.size();
        for(int i = 0; i<size-1; i++){
            // debugging code: System.out.println(a);
            String one = a.get(i);
            String two = a.get(i+1);
            if(one.length() == 0 || two.length() == 0){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("String is empty");
            }
            if(one.length() > two.length() || // if the first string is greater than or equal     to
            one.length() == two.length()){    // the second string, the second string is removed
                a.remove(two);
            } else {
                a.remove(one); // first string is removed if it has a smaller size than the     second
            }
            if(size%2 != 0){ // increments i if we are looping through an odd number of strings
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you remove elements from the list you iterate over, that modification needs to be taken into account in the loop condition. Your continuation condition `i<size-1` does not evaluate the current length of the list. That means that the loop has no idea that the list changed and thus runs too often, letting `i` become too large which causes that Exception.

Comment: Check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. It also has tips about evaluating what you think the code is doing. Take a step back from the code and describe in words what you want the code to accomplish. What should the final result be? Can you illustrate with some examples? Feel free to [edit] your question with these details if you want some more suggestions.

Comment: For example, are you trying to iterate over pairs of elements in the list. Or do you want to compare the length of one string to all of the strings following it?

Comment: Plus, the problem is under-specified. What do you do if both words in the pair have the same length?  Maybe your instructor is expecting you to realize the problem description is incomplete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your list.size will be shorter when you remove but your condition i < size-1 is i < 6( for explame : {"four", "score", "and", "seven", "years", "ago"} ) so when your list.size become lower than i , it will be error;

maybe you can change :

for(int i = 0; i<size-1; i++) - > for(int i = 0; i<a.size-1; i++){

Answer (score 0):

If it's hard to tell where the problem is, making your code *simpler* will make it easier to debug/analyse and most times avoid problems altogether.

Try breaking the steps down, something like this:

```
public static void removeShorterStringsList(List<String> a) {
    if (a.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("List is empty");
    }

    int shortestLength = a.stream()
        .mapToInt(String::length)
        .min()
        .getAsInt();

    System.out.println(
        a.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.length() > shortestLength)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "))
    );
}
```